# Does DateTime roundtrip with respect to ToUniversalTime and ToLocalTime?

Tags: .net, datetime, time, timezone

In the following code snippet, is the round-trip property that I'm asserting guaranteed to hold for any `DateTime` value?

```
DateTime input = GetAnyDateTime();
DateTime roundtripped = input.ToUniversalTime().ToLocalTime();
Assert.IsTrue(input == roundtripped);
```

Does the assertion also hold for the reverse kind of round-trip (`input.ToLocalTime().ToUniversalTime()`)?

Possible edge cases would be time zones, daylight savings, leap seconds, unrepresentable or ambiguous local times, ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It does, but only through some dark magic hackery going on under the hood.

When you look at `DateTimeKind`, you will see three options, `Unspecified`, `Utc` and `Local`.  This information is packed into two bits of the internal 64-bit representation.  Since there are four possible values that can be represented with two bits, that leaves room for a fourth kind.

And as Jon Skeet uncovered and described [in this blog post](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/05/02/more-fun-with-datetime/), *there is indeed a hidden fourth kind*!  Basically, it is `Local` but is treated differently when resolving ambiguous times.

Of course, outside of .Net, `DateTime` with `Local` kind doesn't round trip anyway.  It gets treated as `Unspecified` on the return - unless you tell it otherwise.  I blogged about this [here](http://codeofmatt.com/2013/04/25/the-case-against-datetime-now/).  The better alternative is `DateTimeOffset`.

Of course, this is just one of many screwy things with `DateTime` in .Net.  Another great post by Jon Skeet [here](http://noda-time.blogspot.com/2011/08/what-wrong-with-datetime-anyway.html) discusses a few of them.

The best solution is to stop using any of the built-in date and time types, and get familiar with [Noda Time](https://code.google.com/p/noda-time/) instead.  You may have to still use `DateTime` or `DateTimeOffset` when interacting with other systems, but you can use Noda Time internally, and let it do all of the conversions for you.

**Additional Information**

You asked about round-tripping through another format, such as ticks or a string.

- `DateTime.Ticks` in .Net isn't a great serialization format, because it doesn't adhere to a single point of reference.  They are integer number of 100-nanosecond intervals since midnight Jan 1, 0001.  But they are not respective to UTC - rather, they align with the `Kind` that is being used.  In other words:

  ```
  var utcNow = DateTime.UtcNow;
  var now = utcNow.ToLocalTime();
  var equal = utcNow.Ticks == now.Ticks; // false
  ```

  Compare that to JavaScript, which uses the Jan 1 1970 reference point - *at midnight UTC*.  Any time you get a number of ticks, such as with `.getTime()`, it reflects UTC.  You can't actually get ticks in local time with a simple method call, because they are meaningless in JavaScript.  Other languages work like this as well.

  Also, the Gregorian calendar that we use didn't go into effect until 1582, so it's screwy that 1/1/0001 is is their reference point.  Dates before 1582 are meaningless on our current scale and have to be translated.
- Strings can be a great way to transmit date and time values, because they are human readable.  But you should also make sure that they are machine readable without any ambiguity.  For example, don't use a value like `1/4/2013`, because without additional culture information, you won't know if that's January 4th or April 1st.  Instead, use one of the ISO8601 formats.

  When using these with `DateTime`, you can use the `"o"` format string, which can round-trip the kind.  It appends a `Z` for `Utc` kinds, or the local offset for `Local` kinds.

  ```
  var dt = new DateTime(2013,6,4,8,56,0);  // Unspecified Kind
  var iso = dt.ToString("o");              // 2013-06-04T08:56:00.0000000

  var dt = DateTime.UtcNow;                // Utc Kind
  var iso = dt.ToString("o");              // 2013-06-04T15:56:00.0000000Z

  var dt = DateTime.Now;                   // Local Kind
  var iso = dt.ToString("o");              // 2013-06-04T08:56:00.0000000-07:00
  ```

  When parsing from this format, if you don't have an offset, then the kind will be `Unspecified`. But if you have a `Z` or *any* offset, then by default the kind will be `Local`.  It will also apply whatever offset you provide, so that the result is the equivalent *local* time.  So if you want to apply it correctly, you must explicitly tell it to round-trip the kind.

  ```
  var dt = DateTime.Parse("2013-01-04T15:56:00.0000000Z");
  var kind = dt.Kind;  // Local - incorrect!
  var s = dt.ToString("o");  // "2013-01-04T08:56:00.0000000-07:00"  (ouch!)
  ```

  Instead:

  ```
  var dt = DateTime.Parse("2013-01-04T15:56:00.0000000Z",
                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
  var kind = dt.Kind;  // Utc  - that's better.
  var s = dt.ToString("o");  // "2013-01-04T15:56:00.0000000Z"  (nice!)
  ```

  Of course, you are much better off working with `DateTimeOffset`.  When you serialize this in ISO8601 format, you always get a complete representation:

  ```
  var dto = DateTimeOffset.Now;
  var iso = dto.ToString("o");   // 2013-06-04T08:56:00.0000000-07:00
  ```

  This format aligns with [RFC3339](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3339.txt), which describes this profile of the ISO8601 spec, and is quickly becoming the de-facto standard for serializing timestamps between dissimilar systems.  IMHO - you should use this format whenever possible.  It is *vastly* superior to other formats such as RFC1123 that you commonly see on the web.  [Here are some more details on various date/time formats](http://www.hackcraft.net/web/datetime/).

`DateTimeOffset` values will always roundtrip, as they carry all relevant information in the serialized format.  So will `Unspecified` and `Utc` kinds of `DateTime`.  Just steer clear of `Local` kinds of `DateTime`.  Those will easily get you into trouble.

**Answer Please?**

Just reading this again, and realized while I provided lots of details, I didn't *directly* answer your question.  The tests will fail if the input kind is *already* of the first kind that you're converting to.  Let's look at the two test conditions:

- `someDateTime == someDateTime.ToUniversalTime().ToLocalTime()`

  This will fail if the original value is already of `Utc` kind.

  This test will also fail if the original value is invalid in the local time zone during a DST spring-forward transition.  For example, `2013-03-10 02:00:00` does not exist in US Pacific Time.  However, since it doesn't exist, you probably won't encounter it in your data.  So it's probably not a valid test condition.
- `someDateTime == someDateTime.ToLocalTime().ToUniversalTime()`

  This will fail if the original value is already of `Local` kind.

Also note that the `Kind` property does not participate in the equality check.  So while the input of either of these could be `Unspecified`, the output of test 1 will always have a `Local` kind, and the output of test 2 will always have a `Utc` kind - *but the tests will pass anyway*.

Comment: Good to know. That information is applicable to my use case. But what if I were to discard that information (maybe by round-tripping over a string representation or `Ticks`)?

Comment: Thanks. My case is, in fact, a serialization with style "o". I found it annoying that I need to specify special options when parsing it (due to the "z" postfix). I expected to get an unchanged DateTime value of kind Utc or Unspecified. DateTime.Parse converts to local though, which is why I tried to use ToUniversalTime. That's where my question comes from. This appears to be a feature design flaw. I can't see any reason why it should do this.

Comment: Yes, very flawed.  So very many people have complained to Microsoft about DateTime, but they are more concerned with backwards compatibility than providing a good solution.  Enter NodaTime - which has a slightly higher learning curve, but keeps you from getting into trouble.

Comment: Of course, the down side of using NodaTime is you have another dependency.  The upside is that it's written by Jon Skeet (and contributors), so the quality is A++

Answer (score 1):

The [reference source](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/datetime.cs) confirms the accepted answer linking to Jon Skeet's explanation and might be of interest:

```
//
// There is also 4th state stored that is a special type of Local value that
// is used to avoid data loss when round-tripping between local and UTC time.
// See below for more information on this 4th state, although it is 
// effectively hidden from most users, who just see the 3-state DateTimeKind
// enumeration.
[...]
// For a description of various calendar issues, look at
// 
// Calendar Studies web site, at
```

[`// http://serendipity.nofadz.com/hermetic/cal_stud.htm.`](http://serendipity.nofadz.com/hermetic/cal_stud.htm)

```
[...]
    // The data is stored as an unsigned 64-bit integeter
    //   Bits 01-62: The value of 100-nanosecond ticks where 0 represents 1/1/0001 12:00am, up until the value
    //               12/31/9999 23:59:59.9999999
    //   Bits 63-64: A four-state value that describes the DateTimeKind value of the date time, with a 2nd
    //               value for the rare case where the date time is local, but is in an overlapped daylight
    //               savings time hour and it is in daylight savings time. This allows distinction of these
    //               otherwise ambiguous local times and prevents data loss when round tripping from Local to
    //               UTC time.
    private UInt64 dateData;
```